# Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app)

Tags: reactjs, firebase

При переходе на вторую вкладку выдает ошибку

```
"Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app)."
```

Подключение к базе

```
export const DB_CONFIG = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
  };
```

Вызываю на 2 страницах

```
import  firebase from 'firebase';
import {DB_CONFIG} from '../Config.js'

this.app = firebase.initializeApp(DB_CONFIG);

        this.database = this.app.database().ref('driversApp/ordersData/').child(key);
```

Comment: А почему конфиг DB_CONFIG - пустой? Может это и есть причина ошибки?

Comment: там все заполнено

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';


const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};

const config = {
    apiKey: "",
authDomain: "",
databaseURL: "",
projectId: "",
storageBucket: "",
messagingSenderId: ""
  };

firebase.initializeApp(config);

firebase.database();
export default firebase;
```

Делаем авторизацию только раз, а потом вызываем где надо 
this.database = firebase.database().ref('driversApp/ordersData/').child(key);